# Devise routing, i get "Something went wrong" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, devise

Im new to rails and im having troubles figuring out the routing in rails 3 with devise

When i rout to the users page i get this ugly error :  http://s9.postimage.org/nlyxhlk5b/Devise_routing.png

in my routes i have

```
#Resources for users

devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }

resource :users do
  get 'welcome'
end
```

These are my user routes

**UPDATED**

```
                       root        /                                               members#welcome
           new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                        devise/sessions#new
               user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                        devise/sessions#create
       destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                       devise/sessions#destroy
              user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                       devise/passwords#create
          new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                   devise/passwords#new
         edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                  devise/passwords#edit
                            PUT    /users/password(.:format)                       devise/passwords#update
   cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                         devise/registrations#cancel
          user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                devise/registrations#create
      new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                        devise/registrations#new
     edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                           devise/registrations#edit
                            PUT    /users(.:format)                                devise/registrations#update
                            DELETE /users(.:format)                                devise/registrations#destroy
```

Should i maybe not have 2 user resources ? i believe they might be conflicting somehow or am i just missing something ?

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention that i am overriding the default devise registration controller

```
 class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  # Redirect to welcome page after a successful registration
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/users/welcome'
  end
 end
```

Comment: Im unsure as to why you are setting resources :users do sign_in, sign_out and sign_up. infact unless your overriding the devise controllers you only need devise_for :users

Comment: Well i made a user scaffold and that made routes for the user, i dont remember what they where but i just wanted to be sure i was using the device ones :) and yes i am overriding the devise registration controller since i want to route to my `welcome` page instead of the default on successful user registration - ill update the post with the Registration controller

Comment: are you using :confirmable with devise?

Comment: if not you can just use this in your routes, 
  authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'controller#action'
  end

Comment: no im not using :confirmable but users have to be approved by admins, and i don't want to send all users to the `welcome` page but only the newly registered ones, it will let them know their account is inactive till approved

Comment: have a look at the default behaviour of the registrations controller, create action in devise https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb, you should see that it has its own path for unconfirmed accounts, could just amend this and let devise take care of the routing for you

Comment: never mind i fond the problem, it was completly unrelated to my routes - there was a syntax error in my user controller in one of the methods i wasn't even using lol

Comment: cool, glad you found the issue

Comment: Maybe i celebrated too quickly, now when i try to log in i get `undefined method `session_path'` in `devise/sessions#create` my user routes are the same as in my original post, but this time i cant log in ... lol

Comment: what happens when you remove get sign_in and all thats underneath it

Comment: there is no sign_in anymore - my routing looks like the original post, ill remove the confusing routes :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20010/discussion-between-richlewis-and-matti)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the user controller
Delete the registrations controller

remove

```
resource :users do
get 'welcome'
end
```

add this to your routes

```
# Directing the user after login
 authenticated :user do
root :to => 'recipes#index'
```

end

change

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

To

```
devise_for :users
```

Let me know how that goes

Comment: yup im trying it out, but i have to ask - why 'recipes' ? i have no controller / action with that name :P

Comment: sorry my bad, thats the path for my project lol, this will basically be your controller/action. you will have to create a new controller to show your welcome page or add the welcome action to another controller

Comment: hmm this is not going too well for me, now im gettin this message from  the webbrick server `Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 49ms` and i get a routing error `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil}` damn lol

Comment: we dont need the users controller you set up by scaffolding, devise has its own user setup.put the welcome action in one of your other controllers for now and root to that the way i have described in your routes

Comment: okey it works now and i can log in/out but how can i now get to my usercontrollers index ? `No route matches [GET] "/users"`

Comment: you dont want to get there. give me the name of another controller you are using, pref one that is only accessible to logged in users

Comment: i do need the users controller since i have a activate method and my index sorts approved users from unapproved.. should i overwrite the devise controller ?

Comment: rename your users controller to members, user is conflicting somewhere

Comment: sorry for the late replay but i changed the userController to memberscontroller but i still get `No route matches [GET] "/users"` routing error

Comment: ill post the routes i have now

Comment: what does your routes.rb look like?

Comment: ive updated the orginal question routes, thanks for your help mate its appriciated :)

Comment: wait can i add `resource :member`s to use the methods in there ?

Comment: yes, i was going to suggest that, i invited you to chat to talk through it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20011/discussion-between-richlewis-and-matti)